# Move participant from groupcall to other call (Graph participant invite)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We have a teams bot. In normal scenario, there is an incoming call to an application endpoint (A => bot), the bot sets up another call to a teams user (bot => B) and when connected, the bot invites A into the call it has with B, escalating the last one to a group call.

This works fine using [Example code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/participant-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-invite-participants-to-an-existing-group-call-replacing-an-existing-peer-to-peer-call).

However, in some situations, the initial call already has escalated to a group call (essentially, we want to do the same process, starting with the result of the former, after B disconnected) So:

1. Call 1 [A => Bot]
2. call 2 [Bot => B]
3. A invited into call 2
4. B disconnects from call 2 (thus call 2 only has A and Bot as participants)
5. call 3 [Bot => C)
6. A invited into call 3 **(this fails)**

We tried this with the same json structure and with including the participantId (as suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/participant-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-5-move-one-participant-from-one-meeting-to-another)) however, we receive

```
"resultInfo": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.resultInfo",
                "code": 481,
                "subcode": 10021,
                "message": "addParticipants failed for participant 4:+********. Underlying reason: Call/Transaction Does Not Exist Or Has Ended. DiagCode: 481#10021.@"
            }
```

in the callback (the actual invite request succeeds) resulting in no changes to the initial call and a groupcall consisting of only 2 participants (the bot and C). Now the call definitively still is there, so i guess the error message is of - or - the çall'actually means meeting, which is different then a groupcall (if i am correct).

Is this scenario possible and if so, what do we need to change?

(ps. I know it will work if we send the invite the other way around, so invite C into call 2, but this is not preferred for us)

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share the call id with repro UTC time? so that we can investigate from our end.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT, i need to prepare this again to reproduce - will do so monday and let you know. Thnx

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT, 08:16:54.320 we invited participant (pstn) from a groupcall, to call 401f6000-5c0a-4693-bd37-2e7e4ede9bdb (Callchainid: d9d1f1a6-8ff3-44e9-8878-cb7e3442b9a8, RequestId: 66066ed7-ef7c-4e00-948b-6b1fd0bd258e).

08:16:55.870; we received the inviteParticipantsOperation callback "resourceUrl":"/communications/calls/401f6000-5c0a-4693-bd37-2e7e4ede9bdb/operations/f6733c68-4654-459c-98a4-e04ff4a8c60b": Underlying reason: Call/Transaction Does Not Exist Or Has Ended. DiagCode: 481#10021.@

Comment: Thanks for providing information. we will provide this to engineering team and let you know the update.

Comment: @user1515791 - Engineering team has provided the following route cause. The reason #6 fails is because the replacement link used is not A's replacement link from call #2, but rather it is B's replacement link. Because B already left the call in call #2, invitations using that link will fail with the error "Call is already ended."